# Check the SMS delivery status in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sendsmsactivity

I want to check the SMS delivery status in ***journey builder*** to take further action based on the status.

Is there any way to check delivery status in the journey itself?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't away to check the delivery status of SMS in Journey Builder itself.  But there is a new data view that may be useful to you for this:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5

You could query this and update the DE with the info you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, @Gaines for taking a look. I appreciate your response.